# To track in how many device the app is currently installed in android

Tags: android, google-play

I want some tool for tracking the use of my android Application  like in how many device App is currently installed , is der any crash in the app ,Average usage time of my app,how many user has uninstall the App.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use 'Google Analytics' integration in your android app for accessing reports on 'Mobile App Acquisition' and is highly recommended for the reasons described below:

**Find out how often your mobile apps are installed and opened.**
The Acquisition reports give you data about how users find your app, including the total number of new users and the most popular devices and operating systems. Use these reports to find out how often your app is downloaded and installed, and how successful certain marketing campaigns are in attracting users.

Use the New Users report to identify characteristics of the user groups adopting your app. The Sources report can help you discover which channels you can optimize to attract more downloads and launches. The Google Play Referral Flow report displays the app downloads and installs from the Google Play Store in an intuitive and interactive visualization.

**New Users**
This report gives you an overview of the first launches, or the number of sessions in which the app is opened for the first time on a device, including the total number of New Users, their Operating System, App Version, and the Country/Territory. Note that Users includes all users, both new users and the returning users that have opened your app at least once during the selected time period.

You can find more in-depth data on all your users and how they interact with your app with the Audience and Behavior reports.

**App Marketplace**
Discover which marketplaces users visit to download your app. Native operating system platforms, like Google Play, and third-party platforms both appear in this report.

**Sources**
With the Sources report, you can get data about how well your apps perform in different marketplaces, including the iTunes Store for iOS apps and the Google Play for Android apps. Use this report to find out how users discover your app, including what drives them to your page in the marketplace, and what contributes to app downloads.

**Google Play Referral Flow**
The Google Play Referral Flow visualizes how users move through each stage of the acquisition process - from finding to launching your app - in an intuitive way.

**AdWords reports**
The AdWords reports give you post-click performance metrics for users who clicked on your AdWords ad and then installed and started using your mobile app. These reports show exactly how your search and display campaigns are performing and offer rich insights into the kind of users they’re driving to Google Play.

To use the AdWords reports, you must [link your AdWords and Google Analytics accounts](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033961) and [enable auto-tagging](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1733663).

To setup google analytics follow the instructions detailed on the following link: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2587086?hl=en&ref_topic=2587085&rd=1

There are other alternatives if you do not wish to integrate Google Analytics, such as Flurry Analytics (now part of Yahoo) which is free to use at any scale of your app.

You will get detailed integration instructions at the following link:
https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/analytics/gettingstarted/android/

Integrating Flurry SDK as per link above (default integration steps in which API call `FlurryAgent.setCaptureUncaughtExceptions(false);` is omitted) lets Flurry report uncaught exceptions in your app.

You may also want to try Crashlytics by Fabric.io for in depth analysis of app crash reports. Follow the Fabric (& Crashlytics) integration instructions detailed at the following link:
https://docs.fabric.io/android/fabric/integration.html

Answer (score 0):

Use the Google Analytics for it...
Link is as follow :- [Google Analytics](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/08/android-integrating-google-analytics-v4/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable google analytics for your project and then you can track the app.

after enabling, all you need to do is make a class to track the activities. here is example of that.

```
public class AnalyticsApplication extends Application {
private Tracker mTracker;

/**
* Gets the default {@link Tracker} for this {@link Application}.
* @return tracker
*/
synchronized public Tracker getDefaultTracker() {
if (mTracker == null) {
  GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
  // To enable debug logging use: adb shell setprop log.tag.GAv4 DEBUG
  mTracker = analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker);
}
return mTracker;
} 
}
```

now create an object of this class..

```
AnalyticsApplication application = (AnalyticsApplication) getApplication();
mTracker = application.getDefaultTracker();
```

And override your methods like onResume, onCreate and add trackers in that.

```
Log.i(TAG, "Setting screen name: " + name);
mTracker.setScreenName("Image~" + name);
mTracker.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());
```

For more information... visit the link   https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/

Comment: Is der any third part Tool Available  for same  ??

Comment: You can try Parse, using that you can customize your tracker in the way you want!!   https://parse.com/products/analytics

Comment: but from your requirements, you can use GA, it will Serve your purpose

Comment: how to track the bug using ga can u send some links

Comment: You can use this link https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/exceptions

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty more ways of tracking uninstalls. You can run a ping service from the device to the server periodically. You can also send blank notifications intermittently to make sure the app is still on the device. You can ignore rendering these notifications to your users.

If you are looking for a tool that does app engagement and analytics then you can check out clevertap.com They provide uninstall tracking right out of the box with the ability to send automated emails to them.

If you were looking for a pure technical explanation of how GCM and Apple track uninstalls then you can read about it here. Track App Uninstalls effectively (https://blog.clevertap.com/track-app-uninstalls-effectively/) I have also covered alternative methods if you wanted to implement the uninstall tracking yourself!

Good luck.